# Bytestring can't be used

Tags: haskell

I created some code in the past which use Data.Bytestring.Lazy. Now, when I try to compile it, everithing what I get is a bunch of errors. Example of error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `BL.ByteString'
                with actual type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
    In the return type of a call of `decompress'
    In the second argument of `decrypt', namely `(decompress fc)'
    In the second argument of `BL.filter', namely
      `(decrypt (extractKey tkey) (decompress fc))'
```

... And many errors like this ...

My import of bytestring: import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL.
What to do with this?

EDIT:

THANKS for help. With explicit package version, everything works fine. But, I don't like this solution. When I try to unregister one of the two installed bytestring packages. Many packages will be broken. The newest package version break small amount of packages (no core packages). How to repair packeges which are destroyed by unregistering package?

EDIT:

No, it's not working fine with explicit package version. I wrote edit before I tried it physically. It was mistake. Nothing works.

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple versions of bytestring installed? (`ghc-pkg list bytestring`)

Comment: To expand on the comment from @user2407038, this looks like a "cabal hell" issue.  Are you using [cabal sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html)?

Comment: There was an option in GHC to solve this. Please try to compile with `ghc -package=bytestring-0.10.0.2 ...` . Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have solved the problem. The evil package was zlib which uses old version of bytestring, but all packages for encryption uses the new version. When I threw away code for compression, my program compiled. Now, I'm looking for some compression algorithms...

Comment: You're better off unregistering all the packages that depend on the new bytestring and reinstalling them against the version of bytestring that came with your compiler. Otherwise, you'll eventually run into this situation again.

Comment: sandboxes sandboxes sandboxes